# How to draw a filled square behind text in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I am developing a grid based game in libgdx. What i want is to know how can i draw a square tile with number written on it which can be moved and scaled. 
Its stupidity to design thousands of textures for these numbers and use them as sprites.I want to know if there is any container class in which i can dynamically add text and and set background too.

Comment: How are you drawing the numbers now? a font? or combining single digit sprites? Why does the number have to be part of the tile?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVslS9wPmq4 like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Scene2d UI](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui) components such as [`Label`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html) to create styled text boxes.

Scene2d allows you to do layout and styling of a wide range of components that can easily be manipulated using [`Action`s](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Action.html), or you can create your own components by extending [`Actor`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html).

To create and display a `Label`, create a `Stage` and add the `Label` to it.

Answer (score 0):

In this context I assume you by "tile" just mean a rectangle.

You don't say anything about what you are doing now. How you draw the numbers.
So this answer is based on almost zero information.

**Solution 1:**
Use a font with a background color.

**Solution 2:**
You know the number/how many digits. You know the size of the font. Calculate the size of the text on screen. Use a single narrow background sprite and tile it behind the text.

**Solution 3:**
Use a textbox from Scene2d.

Comment: I am very much new to Libgdx .The game is,If adjacent tiles match then the number is incremented on the tile where user taps.Tile with number 1-7 have unique texture background then textures repeat above number 7 after every 7 tiles. I have algorithm for that to identify number then place texture behind it accordingly but the problem is i dont know how to draw these tiles.
Solution 1:I dont know how to do it.
Solution 2: This is what i was actually doing,placing Image on grid. But it is stupid to draw hundreds of Png images with numbers,Right?
Solution 3:Again I dont know anything about it.